# Get access permissions for a file for a current windows-user

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, windows-authentication, file-permissions

How can I get access permissions for a file for the current user (user that runs the application) ?

```
public static DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);    
var dirSecurity = di.GetAccessControl();
var accRules = dirSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
```

`accRules` contains array of `FileSystemAccessRule`. I guess these are the permissions for different roles.

How can I know which of them applies for the user that currently runs the application ?